# Misfiring plugs

Tags: sparkplugs, kia, sportage

My Kia Sportage has been running on only two of 4 cylinders. The 2 plugs don't fire at all even when they are replaced. The coil works perfectly if they are interchanged. Wires are in perfect condition. Using a different engine control unit enables one additional plug to fire, but gears don't change. With the original unit, gears change but performance is low and there is constant jerking/vibration. Do I have a way out?

Comment: Have you replaced the plugs or at least tried them in a different position to make sure they aren't the issue?

Comment: I have done all but problem persist. infact I was made to overhaul the engine to clean up valves but didn't correct the problem